# Regex, finding filename in quotes. c#

Tags: c#, regex

I got this string:

> ("{FAEC7O"0-207F-765VB3-BF4B-00BCSJ23BC}") = "test", "test\test.csproj", "{2943HBS98000CC-FFDD-KD89E-9F84-08923HSB00CCd67}")

I want to get as a result test/test.csproj. How do I find this part of the string which has quotes and a .csproj at the end.

Comment: In addition to the immediately downvote add at least a Text with "Hello Mr Yve, please let us know what you've already tried and show us some example code you wrote. We are not a Code Writing machine and are here to help, not to solve your homework or complete your customer desires."

Comment: any attempts from you? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

Since you specifically mentioned regex, here's a classic regex for you :

```
string pattern = @"""[^""]*\.(csproj)""";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match match = reg.Match(yourString);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value); // Group[0] is the full match.
```

I would go into explaining this if you ask, but in all honesty, I find the other answer more elegant. It looks like you're working with a list, so it would be proper to split it up first. (although the [^""]* portion of my regex accomplishes this in a way.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, split the string by every comma.

```
("{FAEC7O"0-207F-765VB3-BF4B-00BCSJ23BC}") = "test", "test\test.csproj", "{2943HBS98000CC-FFDD-KD89E-9F84-08923HSB00CCd67}")
```

In this case you get can get your wanted result with getting index 1:

```
string str = ("{FAEC7O\"0 - 207F - 765VB3 - BF4B - 00BCSJ23BC}\") = \"test\", \"test\\test.csproj\", \"{2943HBS98000CC-FFDD-KD89E-9F84-08923HSB00CCd67}").Split(',')[1];

index 0: "{FAEC7O"0-207F-765VB3-BF4B-00BCSJ23BC}") = "test",
index 1: "test\test.csproj", 
index 2: "{2943HBS98000CC-FFDD-KD89E-9F84-08923HSB00CCd67}")
```

Works kinda the same with regex:

```
var str = Regex.Split(("{FAEC7O\"0 - 207F - 765VB3 - BF4B - 00BCSJ23BC}\") = \"test\", \"test\\test.csproj\", \"{2943HBS98000CC-FFDD-KD89E-9F84-08923HSB00CCd67}"), ",")[1];
```

Good luck!